# Click notify on notification bar don't auto open link

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My application used notify of APNS. When server send a notify to client with a link. I click to notify on notification bar, application will open link in notify on webview. My problem is, when application run active or Background, it run normal and load link OK. But when application don't active, i click to notify, it will don't load link in notify, it only load old link in NSUserDefaults or link "http://staging.nhomxe.vn". This is my code:

APPDELEGATE.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application 
didReceiveRemoteNotification:
(NSDictionary*)userInfo

{

NSLog(@"Received notification: %@", userInfo);
NSDictionary *data = [ userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
for(NSString *key in data) {
    NSString *info = [data objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"thong tin nhan dc: %@ : %@", key, info);
}

NSString *message = [userInfo valueForKey:@"link"] ;
//NSArray *info = [message componentsSeparatedByString:@"&@"];
//NSString *body = [info objectAtIndex:0];
//NSString *link = [info objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"Thong tin Link: %@",message);
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue:message forKey:@"LINK"];

UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning"
 message:message
 delegate:nil
 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
 otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
 [alertView show];

ViewController *vc = (ViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:message];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[vc.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
[vc.webView3 loadRequest:urlRequest];

}
```

MYVIEWCONTROLLER.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{   NSString *link = NULL;
NSUserDefaults *data = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
link = [data objectForKey:@"LINK"];
NSString *connect = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://staging.nhomxe.vn"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
if(connect == NULL)
{
    NSLog(@"Server hiện tại đang bảo trì. Ứng dụng sẽ đóng ngay bây giờ.!");
    UIAlertView * alert =[[UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:@"Warning"
                                                     message:@"Server hiện tại đang bảo trì. Ứng dụng sẽ đóng ngay bây giờ."
                                                    delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles: nil];
    alert.tag = 1;
    [alert show];

}else
{   if(link == NULL)
{

    NSString *linkWeb = @"http://staging.nhomxe.vn";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:linkWeb];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
    [self.webView3 loadRequest:urlRequest];
}else{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
    [self.webView3 loadRequest:urlRequest];
    //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"LINK"];
    //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    //NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    //[defaults setValue:NULL forKey:@"LINK"];
}

}
// Schedule the runScheduledTask in 5 seconds
aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target:self selector:@selector(runScheduledTask) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When App is not running in Background

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application 
didReceiveRemoteNotification:
(NSDictionary*)userInfo
```

Would not be called you Should handle your data something like this..

In your  AppDelegate.m within didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method do something like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  NSDictionary* userInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];
    NSDictionary * data = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];


for(NSString *key in data) {
    NSString *info = [data objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"thong tin nhan dc: %@ : %@", key, info);
}

//.…COntinue with your Execution So on…. You will get the data in the Data Dictionary which you are looking for 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you don't have code to start app from notification.

Take a look at `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`. If app starts from notification, you'll have `launchOptions`.

If you have remote notification, you'll have `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` key in `launchOptions`.

> UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey
>
> The presence of this key indicates that a remote notification is available for the 
>   app to process. The value of this key is an
>   NSDictionary containing the payload of the remote notification. See
>   the description of application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: for
>   further information about handling remote notifications.